# Can html images only be from the web?

Tags: html, image

Can you only link an image from the internet on html? Can you use a image from your desktop instead? I am worried about the image link breaking and having to replace them and besides i have a lot of images on my laptop.

Comment: If you want other people on other computers to see it, then yes you'll need to put the image online somewhere.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I don't think that's what ThatProgrammer's talking about. But yes, that's true.

Comment: @TheJuniorProgrammer Possibly not? They're question is a little unclear as to whether they're looking to just use local html files or not.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan I agree on that as well, but I'm fairly sure ThatProgrammer's talking if he / she can link images from local or online.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can link images from the internet and your files

Say you have `index.html` and you have a folder named `img` in the same folder as `index.html`. You can reference to it using the `img` tag:

```
<img src="img/image.png">
```

Or you want an image from the internet, then do this:

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/">
```

Of course, HTML knows that if you have a http:// in your src, then it's from the web, otherwise, it's a local file.

Also, if you want to upload your HTML file to the web, then you must upload the image / image folder as well, or else the image won't show. Unless the image is from the internet, then it'll show. Until the owner of the online image deletes or moves it...

Comment: Thanks, however the first example doesn't work for me. When i try to link the image offline it doesn't appear.

Comment: @ThatProgrammer Do you have the image in the same folder as your HTML file?

Comment: And if you want to make it easier, do what @SuperBiasedMan says: put the image in the same folder as the HTML file, and just reference to it as `_imagename_._extension_`

Comment: my image is in the same folder as my index.html file.

Comment: @ThatProgrammer Then good, reference to it as imagename.png/jpg/whatever

Comment: nvm i fixed it. Thanks all of you for your help.